# Dart function for waiting for an async function to finish

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I currently have:

```
 loadCalendar() async {
    this.eventssync = await gettingCalendar();
    Map<DateTime, List> eventCal = getEvents(eventssync);
    print ("Before eventCal");
    print (eventCal);
  }
```

I was wondering why the above doesn't work? gettingCalendar is called after getEvents and the printing.

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't work?  What is the implementation of `gettingCalendar`?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is it doing, and how is that different from what you are wanting it to do? If it is throwing an error, what does the error message say?